# I can't open sub directory in php

Tags: php, html

I am trying to open a sub folder when user clicked on main directory url link. It does not either show any errors or content.

Here is my php code to open main folder which is working fine.

```
$loc = 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/www.test.in/stRec';
if (is_dir($loc)){
  if ($dh = opendir($loc)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){                   
    echo'<a href="Subdirectory.php?dir='.$file.'">'.$file.'</a>';
  }
 }
}
```

Code to open sub directory which shows no content.

```
if(isset($_GET['dir'])) {
$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$loc = 'C:/Apache24/htdocs/www.test.in/stRec'.$dir;
if (is_dir($loc)){
  if ($dh = opendir($loc)){
    while (($file = readdir($dh)) !== false){
    echo $file;
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a directory separator: `stRec/'.$dir`?

Comment: yes I tried but it still works same

Comment: If you're not getting an error, then I suspect you're not entering the `if` statements or the `while`. Add some `else` conditions with some echoes to see whether you're not getting in the `is_dir` or the `opendir`

Answer (score 0):

> C:/Apache24/htdocs/www.test.in/stRec'.$dir

path separator on windows is "\"

---

edit:

To get more details:

```
<?php

if (!isset($_GET['dir'])) {
    die('dir not set');
}

$dir = $_GET['dir'];
$loc = 'C:\whatever\path' . $dir;

if (!is_dir($loc)) {
    die('not a dir');
}

if ($handle = opendir($loc)) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        echo "$entry\n";
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
```

Comment: do you have any example

Comment: use "\" instead of "/" on windows. eg  C:\Apache24\htdocs\www.test.in\

Comment: I just tried using "\" but it still looks same not showing content. I don't understand where my code is wrong exactly.

Comment: @Kanna what is the value of `$dir`? does the directory actually exists? maybe try to add more verbose error reporting. i've updated my answer with an example.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the above code, I just tried it shows the error: dir not set, what I need to do in this scenario?

Comment: `$_GET` is an array of variables passed via the URL. eg `http://localhost/?dir=whatever`. now `$_GET['dir'] == "whatever"`